# Запуск тестов из консоли Selenium WebDriver

Tags: maven, junit

Вот, собственно, небольшой проект из трех тестов в Selenium WebDriver+JUnit.

https://github.com/Raindropslolz/TestDemo/tree/master/beheroik

Проект создавался через maven.

Встал вопрос о том как все это дело запустить через консоль. До этого ничего похожего делать не приходилось, так что я даже не представляю с чего начать. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: 1) ссылка не рабочая. 2) `mvn clean install test` запустит, сбилдит и запустит тесты

Comment: Ссылку поправил. Перед выполнением команды нужно перейти в каталог с тестами? К примеру тут лежат файлы проекта с расширением .java. `C:\ IdeaProjects\  ProjectName \ src \ test \   `  и уже отсюда вызывать Вашу команду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам не хватает инстукций в POM файле для билда.

Вам нужно добавить . [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) в ваш pom.xml

```
<project> 
.... 

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

....
</project>
```

далее из каталога, где находится pom.xml выполнить `mvn clean install test`

Comment: 4 часа курил все эти ваши интернеты но решения так и не нашел. Тут ответили за 5 минут. Можно я Вас поцелую?

Comment: @PavelBobrov простите, я мужчина. нельзя

Comment: @ SeniorPomidor, а не подскажете как прервать выполнение тестов. запущенных таким образом? Что нужно закрыть, какой процесс прервать? Или может еще какой способ?

Comment: Ctrl + C прервет процесс

Comment: доброго времени суток:) А не подскажете еще одну вещь? Тесты я запускаю командой mvn clean test site, и потом создаю отчет командой mvn allure:serve. Можно ли как-то это объединить в 1 команду?

Comment: `mvn clean test site allure:serve`

Comment: Вы мой самый любимый stackowerflow-чанин:)